# heroku не изменяет txt file

Tags: python, aiogram, heroku

Есть код:

```
@dp.chat_join_request_handler()
async def start1(update: types.ChatJoinRequest):
try:
    await update.approve()
except:
    pass
with open("users.txt","r") as file:
    f = file.readlines()
file.close()
with open("users.txt","w") as file:
    for i in f:
        print(i)
        file.write(i+"\n")
    file.write(str(update.from_user.id)+"\n")
file.close()
with open("users.txt","r") as file:
    f = file.readlines()
    print(f)
file.close()
with open('3-time.txt', 'r') as file:
    a = int(file.read())
file.close()
await asyncio.sleep(a)
# тут мы принимаем юзера в канал
# а тут отправляем сообщение
with open('3.txt', 'r') as file:
    f = file.readline()
file.close()
```

Дело в том, что на локалке он обновляет файл users.txt, но на хероку нет. Хоть print(f) даже в логах хероку выводит правильный результат, но при клоне выводит исходный файл. В чем проблема?

Comment: Может хероку не умеет хранить файлы?

Comment: Heroku так устроен, что после перезагрузки проекта, все данные сбрасываются к начальным состояниям. По этому хранить данные в текстовых файлах, или с помощью SQLite очень плохая идея. Я рекомендую пользоваться БД. Например, в Heroku бесплатно можно использовать PostgreSQL. Но если не хотите настраивать БД, можете использовать бесплатный json-хостинг сервис - jsonstorage.net. Я сам его использовал, в одном из своих ботов.

Comment: Спасибо за ответ